# TOC - Diagonal language is NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

How to prove that diagonal language is NP hard ?
Any pointers in the direction would help. 
I am aware of  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431074/np-hardness-of-diagonal-language)  question but all the answer gives is a definition of reduction.

**Edit :** Diagonal-language contains all strings **X** s.t. **M<sub>x</sub>(x) = 0** where M<sub>x</sub> is the turing machine whose string encoding is given by x.

Comment: You should give a formal definition of the "diagonal language" in your post.

Comment: @fade2black I added the definition. Does that suffice ?

Comment: See this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69448/show-that-halting-problem-mathsfhp-text-is-mathsfnp-text-hard) about NP-hardness of the halting problem. Almost the same proof works for your case, can you tell why?

Comment: @Ariel I get it. "Given a SAT formula φ, construct a Turing machine M which iterates over all truth assignments for φ, and so determines if φ is satisfiable or not. If it is, it halts. If it isn't, it doesn't halt (gets into an infinite loop)." In this case the reduction machine will give code of M. Right ?

Comment: I found out later that [this] (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81141/to-show-that-any-language-l-in-np-is-many-one-reducible-to-hp/) link can help too.